# Office 2007 - run ONLY the Infopath .MSI file again?

Tags: deployment, microsoft-office-2007

***CN:  Office 2007 with admin .MSP file, how to add a new feature and redeploy without removing "one off Office apps (like OneNote)" when the admin .MSP file runs??***

I have created a script that will install Office 2007 with Infopath using a modified admin file.

I have since updated that admin .MSP file to include an additional portion for Infopath that wasn't included originally (a subset feature of Infopath).

**Is there a way to have JUST this subset feature get added/installed to a client's computer?**

The problem I'm running into if I simply rerun my originally script is that...while it does add the component it also removes any additional Office components or apps that aren't a part of that admin .MSP file.

So, if a user had OneNote (for instance) added to their computer after we ran the Office 2007 install script (which didn't have it as a normal part of the install)....when we re-run the script again it adds the subset feature but then removes OneNote.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using config.xml.

Check out the TechNet [Setup reference for the 2007 Office System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179099.aspx):

- [Setup Command-line options for the 2007 Office System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178956.aspx)
- [Config.xml file in the 2007 Office System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179195.aspx)
- [Config.xml file OptionStateID Values](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179006.aspx)
- [Office Customization Tool in the 2007 Office System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that final link actually had a link to here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179141.aspx which stated that the easiest way to do so was to simply create a new .MSP file using the OCT and just selecting the things you wanted to add.  You don't even have to put in a product key, etc. at that point, since it's just running an MSP on top of the original install.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.